# Installing SDL on OSX

Tags: c++, c, macos, gcc, sdl

I downloaded `SDL2-2.0.3`. I ran `./configure && make && make install`.

I've also tried `brew install SDL2`.

This is my main.c

```
//Using SDL and standard IO
#include <SDL2/SDL.h>
#include <stdio.h>
//Screen dimension constants
const int SCREEN_WIDTH = 640;
const int SCREEN_HEIGHT = 480;

int main( int argc, char* args[] ) {
 SDL_Window* window = NULL;
 SDL_Surface* screenSurface = NULL;

 if (SDL_Init( SDL_INIT_VIDEO ) < 0 ) {
   printf( "SDL could not initialize! SDL_Error: %s\n", SDL_GetError() );
 }
}
```

When I run it

```
~:.make main
gcc     main.c   -o main
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_SDL_GetError", referenced from:
      _main in main-d5699d.o
  "_SDL_Init", referenced from:
      _main in main-d5699d.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make: *** [main] Error 1
~:.
```

How do I install this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are failing to link with `libSDL2.{a,dylib}`.

You want:

```
gcc -o main main.c -lSDL2
```

or perhaps:

```
gcc -o main main.c -L/usr/local/lib -lSDL2
```

Comment: Thanks, that compiled!

Answer (score 3):

The following command is installed along with SDL and it tells you the correct switches for compiling and linking:

```
sdl2-config --cflags --libs
```

On my particular machine, that gives:

```
-I/usr/local/include/SDL2 -D_THREAD_SAFE
-L/usr/local/lib -lSDL2
```

That means you can compile and link like this and always be assured of getting the correct settings:

```
g++ main.cpp -o main $(sdl2-config --cflags --libs)
```

Or, you can put it in a Makefile like this (with a TAB at the start of the second line):

```
main:   main.cpp
        g++ main.cpp -o main $$(sdl2-config --cflags --libs)
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to run

- `sdl2-config --cflags` which will give you the compile flags, and
- `sdl2-config --libs` which will give you the linker flags

needed for using SDL2.

The flags will vary by platform which is why you should use `sdl2-config` instead of hardcoding some specific  flags into your Makefile or other build script.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you download the **x64** SDL2 version. You also need to statically link it with `-lSDL2` flag.