# SDL: Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64 (Mac)

Tags: macos, sdl

I'm having problems with SDL2 on my Mac. I've followed the steps saying I should copy the framework to either: ~/Library/Frameworks, or /Library/Frameworks if I have permission, which I have. I've tried both.

Here is the whole error message:

```
make
g++  main.o -o hello
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_SDL_Init", referenced from:
      _main in main.o
  "_SDL_Quit", referenced from:
      _main in main.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [hello] Error 1
```

I've had some experience with SDL before (On Linux) and it was a very straight forward experience. 
Is it a problem with the architecture?

Comment: Have you tried to add the dylib-file with -l, without prepending lib and omitting dylib-extension?

Comment: Have a look here... http://stackoverflow.com/a/33239786/2836621

Comment: I'm sorry, that didn't help me much. I get the same error, and this in addition: "/bin/sh: sdl2-config: command not found"

Comment: You will need to link your application to SDL2 thats for sure. `sdl2-config` may be found inside of your installed framework - check for `/Library/Frameworks/SDL2.framework/Commands` for similar. I don't know how this particular framework is to be used but usually `-framework SDL2` to the compilation options should do it as well. It may require another option to add a search directory for a user installed framework as well.

Comment: Okay, I didn't find /Commands inside `SDL2.framework`, but adding `-framework SDL2` did fix it! Thanks a lot, make it an answer and I'll accept it.